# How to convert direction vector to euler angles?

Tags: math, geometry, euler-angles

I'm looking for a way to convert direction vector (X,Y,Z) into Euler angles (heading, pitch, bank). I know that direction vector by itself is not enough to get the bank angle, so there's also another so-called Up vector.

Having direction vector (X,Y,Z) and up vector (X,Y,Z) how do I convert that into Euler angles?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics it should be moved to http://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @BasBossink I agree, but unfortunately the question is too old to be moved now.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Let's see if I understand correctly.  This is about the orientation of a rigid body in three dimensional space, like an air plane during flight.  The nose of that airplane points towards the **direction vector**

```
D=(XD,YD,ZD) .
```

Towards the roof is the **up vector**

```
U=(XU,YU,ZU) .
```

Then **heading** `H` would be the direction vector `D` projected onto the earth surface:

```
H=(XD,YD,0) ,
```

with an associated angle

```
angle_H=atan2(YD,XD) .
```

**Pitch** P would be the up/down angle of the nose with respect to the horizon, if the direction vector `D` is normalized you get it from

```
ZD=sin(angle_P)
```

resulting in

```
angle_P=asin(ZD) .
```

Finally, for the bank angle we consider the direction of the wings, assuming the wings are perpendicular to the body.  If the plane flies straight towards `D`, the wings point perpendicular to `D` and parallel to the earth surface:

```
W0 = ( -YD, XD, 0 )
```

This would be a bank angle of 0.  The expected Up Vector would be perpendicular to `W0` and perpendicular to `D`

```
U0 = W0 × D
```

with `×` denoting the cross product.  `U` equals `U0` if the bank angle is zero, otherwise the angle between `U` and `U0` is the bank angle `angle_B`, which can be calculated from

```
cos(angle_B) = Dot(U0,U) / abs(U0) / abs(U)
sin(angle_B) = Dot(W0,U) / abs(W0) / abs(U) .
```

Here 'abs' calculates the length of the vector. From that you get the bank angle as

```
angle_B = atan2( Dot(W0,U) / abs(W0), Dot(U0,U) / abs(U0) ) .
```

The normalization factors cancel each other if `U` and `D` are normalized.

Comment: I know this is an old post but it's useful for me too. I'd like to know what is the meaning of `abs(W0) * abs(U0)`. Does the `abs()` function return the lenght of the vector?
And then, shouldn't the `atan2` function take two arguments? x and y? In the example is passed olny one paramater and I can't understand why.

Comment: atan2 assumes two arguments, I suppose that `angle_B = atan2( Dot(W0,U) / Dot(U0,U) / abs(W0) * abs(U0) ) .` should be rather `angle_B = atan2( Dot(W0,U) , Dot(U0,U) / abs(W0) * abs(U0) ) .`

Comment: I voted this answer down since the meaning of abs() is not clear and as Samuel said atan2 expects two parameters, not just one.

Comment: Great algorithm. It solved my problem too :) That problem is part of a thesis however. Therefore do you happen to have a "source" where this is explained in a similar way, so I can reference it?

Comment: I think `angle_B` is wrong for the edgecase where `D=(0,0,1)` or `D=(0,0,-1)`. `W0` and `U0` both end up as `(0,0,0)`. I'm not currently sure how to address that.

Comment: Implementing this in GLSL I've also found that `angle_H` comes out wrong for the same edgecase. However, that's due to GLSL's `atan(0,0)` having undefined behaviour, so findings may vary.

Answer (score 4):

we need three vectors: X1, Y1, Z1 of local coordinate system (LCS) expressed in terms of world coordinate system (WCS). The code below presents how to calculate three Euler angles based on these 3 vectors.

```
#include <math.h> 
#include <float.h> 

#define PI 3.141592653589793 
/**
 * @param X1x
 * @param X1y
 * @param X1z X1 vector coordinates
 * @param Y1x
 * @param Y1y
 * @param Y1z Y1 vector coordinates
 * @param Z1x
 * @param Z1y
 * @param Z1z Z1 vector coordinates
 * @param pre precession rotation
 * @param nut nutation rotation
 * @param rot intrinsic rotation
 */
void lcs2Euler(
        double X1x, double X1y, double X1z,
        double Y1x, double Y1y, double Y1z,
        double Z1x, double Z1y, double Z1z,
        double *pre, double *nut, double *rot) {
    double Z1xy = sqrt(Z1x * Z1x + Z1y * Z1y);
    if (Z1xy > DBL_EPSILON) {
        *pre = atan2(Y1x * Z1y - Y1y*Z1x, X1x * Z1y - X1y * Z1x);
        *nut = atan2(Z1xy, Z1z);
        *rot = -atan2(-Z1x, Z1y);
    }
    else {
        *pre = 0.;
        *nut = (Z1z > 0.) ? 0. : PI;
        *rot = -atan2(X1y, X1x);
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say 3 vectors (named X Y Z for some reason?) you mean the origin (0,0,0) the direction and the up vector? Which is which in your answer?

Comment: X,Y,Z are the LCS coordinate system axises direction vectors in [GCS]. Z is your direction and the two can be obtain by vector multiplication of Z and your up vector

Comment: I don't understand that. Can we please switch to simple GCS for clarity sake?

Comment: LCS is coordinate system of your 'camera' or plane or whatever viewing/moving in its Z direction. (LCS Z axis) = (Z direction vector) = (your direction vector). Orthogonal systems has 3 axises not one so you need 2 perpendicular vectors to it. If your up vector is perpendicular to direction then (Y-axis vector) = (your up vector) and then the X axis is easy X = Z * Y or X = Y * Z ...

Comment: this code snippet is taken from here:

http://geom3d.com/data/documents/Calculation=20of=20Euler=20angles.pdf