# Get rotations for x, y, z axis from 3d coordinate

Tags: javascript, css, math, 3d, geometry

I've been struggling to calculate the **rotationX**, **rotationY** and **rotationZ** (`CSS transform`) from origin to a point in **3d space**. The 3d point can be seen as a vector with the length `1` starting from origin `(0,0,0) to (x,y,z)`. I'm basically trying to calculate the **pitch, yaw and roll** of a vector.

It's similar like the unit circle with a third dimension. But instead of the angle `t`, I'm looking for the rotation around each axis [unit circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvc7G.png)

I've been trying this solution but I seem to miss something: [How to convert direction vector to euler angles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21622956/how-to-convert-direction-vector-to-euler-angles)

Thanks,

Eric

Comment: Just knowing the initial and final positions of a _single_ point is not enough - you also need the pivot point (the center of rotation)

Comment: To clarify: x, y, z is positioned on the surface of a sphere with radius 1. So x, y and z is always between -1 and 1.

Comment: The center of rotation is (0,0,0). You can think of it as rotating a sphere.

Comment: So you have initial _and_ final x, y, z ? If so what are you missing exactly?

Comment: Exactly! The rotation around each axis (rotation around x-axis, y-axis, and z-axis). Need that to rotate a dom element accordingly with a CSS-transform

Comment: But what are you _missing_? You said there was something

Comment: I'm looking for the pitch, roll and jaw for the vector from origin to a point (x, y and z). Like this: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c1/Yaw_Axis_Corrected.svg/2000px-Yaw_Axis_Corrected.svg.png